# Display views horizontally, but hide some of them and add another view if there's not enough room to display them all

Tags: android

I have a horizontal layout that contains a dynamic number of views. If I have enough room horizontally, I want to display all the views that I have, but if I'm missing space, I want to be able to display as many views as I can, and add a last view, that will display how many views are missing.

So, for example, let's imagine that I have 5 views :

On a big screen, it will be displayed like that :
    [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]

And on another, smallest, screen it will be displayed like that :
    [1] [2] [3] [+2]

What is, according to you, the cleanest/easiest way to achieve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Different layout folders - search supporting  multiple screen sizes.

Comment: Also, using a `LinearLayout` with weights will help with even spacing.

Comment: The number of views is dynamic, their respective width as well, different layout folders won't help in this case, I'm afraid. Neither will the weight attribute.